# Expand one element and collapse all other element in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

In knockout is it possible to collapse all other opened row and expand only clicked row.

I am referring this [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XAzW6/34/) for it.

**view -**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items"> <a href="#" data-bind="click: toggle, text:linkLabel"></a> 
    <button data-bind="text:name"></button>
    <div data-bind="visible:expanded">
        <input data-bind="value:name"></input>
    </div>
</ul>
```

**viewModel -**

```
function Sample(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(item.name);
    self.id = ko.observable(item.id);
    self.expanded = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggle = function (item) {
        self.expanded(!self.expanded());
    };
    self.linkLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.expanded() ? "collapse" : "expand";
    }, self);
}

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    var json = [{
        "name": "bruce",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "name": "greg",
        "id": 2
    }]

    var data = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function (item) {
        return new Sample(item); // making things independent here 
    });
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Here its not collapsing already opened row. I tried to fetch complete items in toggle function but it did not work.

I am new to knock out. please suggest.

Update -

I tried this code to make first one extended by default -

```
var index=0;
var data = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function(item) {
      if(index++===0){
      return new Sample(item,true);
    }else{
        return new Sample(item,false);
    }
  });
```

But above given code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very common "problem" when you're working with knockout. You want to keep your `Sample` instances independent, while their behavior might still influence the behavior of any siblings... I usually pick one of three options:

- Move the functionality that influences siblings to the parent viewmodel. For example:

  ```
  var viewModel = function() {
    /* ... */
    self.toggle = function(sample) {
      self.items().forEach(function(candidateSample) {
        candidateSample.expanded(sample === candidateSample);
      });
    }
  };
  ```

  With data-bind:

  ```
  <a data-bind="click: $parent.toggle"></a>
  ```

  Personally, I'd go with this option. Here's it implemented in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxzLsz56/
- Pass siblings to each item:

  ```
  self.items = ko.observableArray();

  var data = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function (item) {
    return new Sample(item, self.items);
  });

  self.items(data);
  ```

  And in `Sample`:

  ```
  function Sample(item, siblings) {
    self.toggle = function() {
      siblings().forEach(/* collapse */);
      self.expanded(true); // Expand
    };
  };
  ```
- Create some sort of postbox/eventhub/mediator mechanism and make a `Sample` trigger an event. Each `Sample` listens to this event and collapses when another `Sample` triggers it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice explanation. Is there any thing available in knockout through which we can make first one by default extended.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to add `if (self.items()[0]) self.items()[0].expanded(true)` to the bottom of your viewmodel constructor.

Comment: If you want to do it in your mapping function, you could do: `json.map(function(item, index) { return new Sample(item, !index) })`. Any index other than `0` will evaluate to `true`, so only the first will be expanded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation. I spent around 4 hours but no result.